# Mutation profiles for Corona viruses in non-human hosts

Tags: mutations, coronavirus, nucleotide

In this question [Mutation rate breakdown by original and mutated nucleotide for Coronaviridae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/98418/36828) mutation profiles for SARS-CoV-2 in humans are given. It is a known fact that mutation profiles are dependent on the host species and it was speculated that the Omicron variant of SARS-CoV-2 evolved at least partly in a non-human host based on its specific mutation profile.

My question is: What are some mutation profiles for SARS-CoV-2 in non-human hosts? All known non-human hosts count.

Comment: So, what have you found so far?

Comment: @bob1: No published numbers so far, some PCA plots showing different ellipses for mutation profiles for different species is all I have seen yet.

Comment: You should add the information you found to the question - prior research helps keep your question from being closed. Note that serial passage in animals in the lab is generally considered "gain of function" research, so won't have been done!

Comment: @bob1: There are data from natural occurring outbreak among animals (mink farms and white tailed dear come immediately to my mind), and also infection in other animals show typically mutations specific to that animal (hamsters are the animal model for Covid-19, to mention another species.

Comment: I second bob1: add the data to the question and explain why it is inadequate for your purposes within the question.